# Axios for multiple request in Reactjs and Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

In my Next.js app, I use axios for data fetching.

Code:

```js
axios
    .post(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/my-bag/`,
        {
            product_with_quantity: [res.data.id,],
            sub_total: res.data.cost,
        },
        config
    )
    .then((res) => {
        const myBagId = res.data.id;
        // use this myBagId when we get requ in myBag
        axios
            .patch(
                `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/product-update-only-quantity/${product.productavailable.id}/`,
                {
                    available_quantity:
                        product.productavailable.available_quantity - quantity, // here state quantity used
                },
                config
            )
            .then((res) => {
                // final get will be after all post, patch done
                axios
                    .get(
                        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/products/${product.slug}/`
                    )
                    .then((res) => {
                        changeProduct(res.data);
                        
                        axios
                            .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/my-bag/${myBagId}/`, config)
                            .then((res) => {
                                changeMyBag(res.data);
                                setLoading(false);
                                setOpenForAdd(true);
                            })
                            .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
```

Here to add a product in bag, I need to do multiple request after completing one by one. But it needs more time. What is the ideal process to do this kind of thing with very minimal time?
Is there anything like caching or some other thing to do?

Comment: why not doing it server side !

Comment: @Spring how? it is a button. when user click it then this function will be called

Comment: Do all these requests need to happen in sequence, or can some of them be done in parallel?

Comment: @juliomalves need to happen in sequence.

Comment: Similar question for Apollo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312276/return-multiple-queries-using-apollo

Comment: @EricBurel No, not similar