# Return multiple queries using Apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, apollo

I am using nextJS for my frontend with apollo and a graphql. And I fetching my queries using the getStaticProps() function. To increase modularity and maintainability I break my queries into multiple queries.

I have a folder structure like:

> src/queries
> getPost.js
> getMenu.js
> getProduct.js
> index.js

And their all queries are put and exported into index.js. The problem is because of multiple queries in the queries folder I am only able to fetch one query at a time.

> import { getPost } from '../src/queries';

This is how I am fetching query using :

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: getPost,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      data: {
          post: data.post.edges
        }
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
};
```

I want to fetch multiple queries like getPost and getProduct. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What is in getPost.js?

Comment: import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const getPost = gql`
  {
    posts {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

Comment: in the query folder, all files contain graphQL queries

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/169 .. or combine multiple await's (use data aliases) with one return (use batching to reduce amount of requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change that => data.posts.edges
```

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: getPost,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      data: {
          post: data.posts.edges
        }
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
};
```